# What's wrong with my function for JavaScript mixins?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, mixins

I'm trying to get an example working for *functional* mixins in JavaScript.

### http://jsfiddle.net/xe207yec/3/

The function is supposed to create a new object from the old, add the properties from the mixin object to it, and return the new object - all the while not mutating the old object so that it can be used as expected.

```
var plusMixin = function(oldObj, mixin) {
    var newObj = oldObj;
    newObj.prototype = Object.create(oldObj.prototype);
    for (var prop in mixin) {
        if (mixin.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            newObj.prototype[prop] = mixin[prop];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};
```

But it's not working. The problem is that the old object is still getting mutated.

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: `var newObj = oldObj;` --- you don't clone an object here, but just create another reference to it.

Comment: Try this: `var foo = []; var bar = foo; foo.push(1);`. What do you expect `bar` to be and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dan - as with your last answer and the provided fiddle reference ... http://jsfiddle.net/xe207yec/6/ ... the code example does not log as supposed, due to lines 94,95. Changing it to ...

```
coffeeTypes = coffeeTypes.concat(peruvian);
coffeeSizes = coffeeSizes.concat(extraLarge);
```

... does the job.

I also took the chance providing an additional purely function based mixin composition approach in order to give the whole matter a spin - http://jsfiddle.net/xe207yec/8/

Comment: You know, this is a Q&A answer format, not a discussion site or forum. You can use the chat to discuss and not having enough reputation doesn't allow you to break rules basically.

Comment: thanks for the hint - I right away will edit my last post according to the rules.

Comment: thanks Peter! very interesting solution, shows how the same result can be achieved with wildly different styles in JavaScript. I may try and work this into the book I'm writing :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because:

```
var newObj = oldObj;
```

This is a straightforward assignment and means `newObj` is now pointing at the same object as `oldObj`.

```
newObj.prototype = Object.create(oldObj.prototype);
```

This may or may not be what you want. If `oldObj` is a function, then this will work. If `oldObj` is not a function (i.e. a plain Object instance), then this will not work and you will need something like the following code:

```
var plusMixin = function(oldObj, mixin) {
    // Construct the [[Prototype]] for the new object
    var newObjPrototype = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(oldObj));

    // Mix-in the mixin into the newly created object
    Object.keys(mixin).map(function(k) {
      newObjPrototype[k] = mixin[k];
    });

    // Use this newly created and mixed-in object as the [[Prototype]] for the result
    return Object.create(newObjPrototype);
};
```

**Rationale:**

You want a prototype chain something like:

```
newObj --> newObj[[Prototype]] --> oldObj[[Prototype]]
```

You then want to mix-in the mixin into `newObj[[Prototype]]`, leaving the mixin (and its `[[Prototype]]`, untouched.

**Usage:**

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.hello = function() {}
function Bar() {};
Bar.prototype.goodbye = function() {}

var foo = new Foo();
var foobar = plusMixin(foo, Bar.prototype); // foobar now has hello and goodbye available to it
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not working for me, not in my example or in a new jsfiddle with your usage.

Comment: OK, sorry to hear that. I'm going to leave this here even though you have answered your own question.

Comment: I'm sure I could get it to work, the problem is probably between the chair and the keyboard, not in your code ;)

Comment: @Dan - Having read your fiddle, my implementation will not work for your category of problem because, IIUC, `oldObj` is a function in your fiddle. My code assumed it was an normal object.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was wrong so I'll answer my own question I guess.

First I want to say that, this may be an odd way to do mixins so do not take my word for it.

The problem wasn't with my function for making the mixins, `plusMixin`, it was with the example code that used it. If you look at the jsfiddle in the question, I was creating the new, mixed-in classes wrong. Here is the correct usage:

```
// build new objects that are combinations of the above
// and put them into a new array
var coffees = coffeeTypes.reduce(function(previous, current) {
  var newCoffee = coffeeSizes.map(function(mixin) {
    // `plusMixin` function for functional mixins, see Ch.7
    var newCoffeeObj = plusMixin(current, mixin);
    return new newCoffeeObj();
  });
  return previous.concat(newCoffee);
},[]);

// we've now defined how to get the price and label for each
// coffee type and size combination, now we can just print them
coffees.forEach(function(coffee){
  printPrice(coffee.getPrice(), coffee.getLabel());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xe207yec/6/